# Moving users to a disabled OU in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to move my disabled users to the proper OU in AD. I have tried to work with this code for a while and the logic seems sound to me. Please let me know what you think:

```
$disalbled= Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | Select SamAccountName | export-csv -Path 'C:\Users\andrew.schilling\Desktop\test\Test.csv' -NoTypeInformation

$disbaledlist = import-csv 'C:\Users\andrew.schilling\Desktop\test\Test.csv' 

foreach ($aduser in $disabledlist) { 
 Move-ADObject -Identity $aduser -TargetPath $OUTransfer 
 }
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: It does not throw an error, yet it does not move the users

Comment: Just a guess, but can it be anything with rights? can you do it manually?

Comment: Do you have more than one domain controller? If you aren't looking at the same domain controller that the move is done on, you won't see the change until replication is complete.

Comment: No we just have one DC

Comment: And the target OU is $OUTransfer = "CN= Disabled Users Accounts,DC=Company,DC=local"

Comment: could it be because you have a type-o in `$disbaledlist`? and your foreach loop have `$disabledlist`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to duplicate what your code appears to be trying to do is this:

```
$OUTransfer = "CN=Disabled Users Accounts,DC=Company,DC=local"

$DisabledUsers = Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly
$DisabledUsers |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName |
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\andrew.schilling\Desktop\test\Test.csv'

$DisabledUsers | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $OUTransfer
```

However,  you're including all the users that are already in the `$OUTransfer` OU.  That's a waste of effort.  I'd replace the last line like so:

```
$DisabledUsers |
    Where-Object DistinguishedName -notlike "*$OUTransfer" |
    Move-ADObject -TargetPath $OUTransfer
```

If you don't need the CSV at all and were just using it as some form of temporary storage, then you can simplify it even further:

```
$OUTransfer = "CN=Disabled Users Accounts,DC=Company,DC=local"

Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly |
    Where-Object DistinguishedName -notlike "*$OUTransfer" |
    Move-ADObject -TargetPath $OUTransfer
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It now throws an error message, which is better than what I was working with.

The error is

Move-ADObject : The operation could not be performed because the object's parent is either uninstantiated or deleted
At line:5 char:5
+     Move-ADObject -TargetPath $OUTransfer

Comment: @AJSKRILLA Are you sure that your `$OUTransfer` is a location that exists and that you have the correct DistinguishedName for it? It looks like in one of your comments above you might have an extra space in your DN

Answer (score 0):

> And the target OU is $OUTransfer = "CN= Disabled Users
>   Accounts,DC=Company,DC=local"

There are two possible problems with this:

1. If it's an OU, it should start with `OU=`. It's possible it's a "Container" and not an "OU". If this is the case, then it's fine.
2. You have a space after the `=`. There should be no space.

Answer (score 0):

First, You need to have the DN of each user in order to move them.

```
Get-Help Move-ADObject -Examples
```

> SYNOPSIS
>       Moves an Active Directory object or a container of objects to a different container or domain.
>
> ```
> -------------------------- EXAMPLE 1 --------------------------
>
> C:\PS>Move-ADObject -Identity "OU=ManagedGroups,DC=Fabrikam,DC=Com"TarrgetPath "OU=Managed,DC=Fabrikam,DC=Com"
> ```

**Change This:**

```
$disalbled= Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | Select SamAccountName | export-csv -Path 'C:\Users\andrew.schilling\Desktop\test\Test.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

**To This:**

```
$disalbled= Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | Select DistinguishedName | export-csv -Path 'C:\Users\andrew.schilling\Desktop\test\Test.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Second, You need to specify what column you are choosing in your CSV (during
    your foreach loop)

**You can do it like this:**

```
foreach ($aduser in $disabledlist) { 
 Move-ADObject -Identity $aduser.DistinguishedName -TargetPath $OUTransfer 
 }
```

**Full Solution:**

```
$OUTransfer = "CN=Disabled Users Accounts,DC=Company, DC=local"
$disalbled= Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | Select DistinguishedName | export-csv -Path 'C:\Users\andrew.schilling\Desktop\test\Test.csv' -NoTypeInformation
$disabledlist = import-csv 'C:\Users\andrew.schilling\Desktop\test\Test.csv'

foreach ($aduser in $disabledlist) { 
    Move-ADObject -Identity $aduser.DistinguishedName -TargetPath $OUTransfer  
 }
```

Comment: I have re-written it as you suggested and still it processes, but gives no error. The current script is

Comment: $OUTransfer = "CN=Disabled Users Accounts,DC=Company, DC=local"

$disalbled= Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | Select DistinguishedName | export-csv -Path 'C:\Users\andrew.schilling\Desktop\test\Test.csv' -NoTypeInformation

$disbaledlist = import-csv 'C:\Users\andrew.schilling\Desktop\test\Test.csv'

foreach ($DistinguishedName in $disabledlist.DistinguishedName) { 
 Move-ADObject -Identity $aduser -TargetPath $OUTransfer 
 }

Comment: @AJSKRILLA I updated the answer to include the full solution. Try that and let me know if it still does not work. - **Tip:** you can `Write-Host $aduser` to see if it is getting the entries out of the CSV correctly.